# SearchTextField display list from left to right

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using SearchTextField pods to display predictive text.

https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField

the following code builds the table with the display list.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchTextField.cellIdentifier)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: SearchTextField.cellIdentifier)
    }

    //cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cell!.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell!.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell!.textLabel?.font = theme.font
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: theme.font.fontName, size: theme.font.pointSize * fontConversionRate)




    cell!.textLabel?.textColor = theme.fontColor
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.textColor = theme.fontColor

    cell!.textLabel?.text = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].title
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].subtitle
    cell!.textLabel?.attributedText = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].attributedTitle
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].attributedSubtitle

    cell!.imageView?.image = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].image

    cell!.selectionStyle = .none

    cell!.detailTextLabel?.textAlignment = .right
    cell!.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right



    return cell!
}
```

resulting with a list of matching titles as labels as can be seen the image

[image]

So my question is how do i get my labels to display the data from right to left?

thanks for any help rendered

Comment: You want it to align right?

Comment: yes. That is exactly what i am trying to achieve

Comment: `(style: .subtitle` does not support the textalignment as right, if you need use custom label else change your style as `(style: .Default)`

Comment: could you please explain how to change style, and where?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the framework, you can set

```
cell!.detailTextLabel?.textAlignment = .right
cell!.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
cell!.textLabel?.text = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].title
cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].subtitle
cell!.textLabel?.attributedText = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].attributedTitle
cell!.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].attributedSubtitle

cell!.imageView?.image = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].image

cell!.selectionStyle = .none
```

inside SearchTextField.swift file from pods.

Comment: tried this. its in the code. does nor work since the labels are the width of the dynamic text and not the parent cell, i think

Comment: I think you should set textalignment first and the text to label.

Comment: not sure i understand your proposed solution. could you please post the code i need to use?

Comment: did not work. the text might be aligned to right but the label is aligned to left and the width of label is exactly the size needed by text value. If the label was the width of the cell this might work but not sure how to define label to width of parent cell

Comment: Width has nothing to do with the textalignment, if you set textalignment to right to correct label it should fulfil your requirement.